# Preview (embed or on new tab) Word and Excel document on Chrome, Edge, .etc

Tags: java, excel, ms-word, embed, preview

Word: http://erp.lixco.com:6065/LixcoResource/resources/quanlytailieu/test/b4646089-ce50-4bd7-8013-9fb02ad0fae5.docx
Excel: http://erp.lixco.com:6065/LixcoResource/resources/quanlytailieu/test/351f8f49-49f9-4b76-8280-670386934285.xlsx

The path these files are returned from the server when I upload. And I save them in the database (mysql).

I want to have the button on my website, when clicked, will review these documents across browsers (embed or on the new tab is also okey)

I'm using Java/JavaServer Faces.
Thanks!

I have tried using byte[] reading, using Jasper report to chang to PDF, ect. But, all of them don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Currently as they stand Edge will attempt to open an Office Online "pre-view" in MS Online Servers.

https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http%3A%2F%2Ferp.lixco.com%3A6065%2FLixcoResource%2Fresources%2Fquanlytailieu%2Ftest%2Fb4646089-ce50-4bd7-8013-9fb02ad0fae5.docx&wdOrigin=BROWSELINK

You cannot preview "Office Files" in a client browser before download, unless like PDF the client has a means to send the Office files back into the Browser plug-in after download.

Here I do not have a plug-in and MS Security says those files are tainted, but I trust you on this occasion. once the file is trusted it can be downloaded to client as a blob.

The blob will be saved as an Office File and anybody with a full Office Suite of applications can preview the contents before allow open for edit.

[image]

The following snippet will fail if file is inaccessible to MSOffice online

```html
<iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http%3A%2F%2Ferp.lixco.com%3A6065%2FLixcoResource%2Fresources%2Fquanlytailieu%2Ftest%2Fb4646089-ce50-4bd7-8013-9fb02ad0fae5.docx" width="640px" height="300px" frameborder="0"/>This is embedded</iframe>
```

An alternative is to use a trusted online pre-viewer :-

[image]

[image]

The following snippet should work if file is accessible to Google online

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://erp.lixco.com:6065/LixcoResource/resources/quanlytailieu/test/b4646089-ce50-4bd7-8013-9fb02ad0fae5.docx&embedded=true" width="640px" height="300px" frameborder="0"/>This is embedded</iframe>
```

### or simpler click here

https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://erp.lixco.com:6065/LixcoResource/resources/quanlytailieu/test/b4646089-ce50-4bd7-8013-9fb02ad0fae5.docx